# how do you extract files from a mhtml file

Tags: compression, mhtml

so i was have a MHTML file someone gave me, i looked it up figured out what it holdsm it holds all the assets of a webpage, how do i decompress this (i use linix just incase if you need to know) i dont know if i would just run a script on my device or would use a website to do it for me (either works)

i am hoping do decompress a mhtml file using either shell commands or a website